# Confused between time complexity of following Dijkstra Algorithm Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

I was trying to implement Dijkstra using Adjacency list in java. I came across one of the implementation of Dijkstra in java, but i am confused whether it is O(ElogV) solution or 0(V^2) solution. Link to the code is : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html.
I am confused because optimized implementation of Dijkstra in c++ involve use of priority queues, but here priority queues are not used.

Comment: Perhaps this is a better fit for: http://cs.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Indeed it is convenient to use a priority queue, in the implementation you link, the fetching of the minimum distance vertex is made by exploring _ALL THE VERTICES_ linearly instead of just taking the top of a min-priority queue ! This is clearly suboptimal although it does the same as using a priority queue.

Comment: So u wanted to say that although the time complexity of the given code is O(ElogV), but code can be made more efficient

Answer (score -1):

The time complexity of Dijkstra's algorithm using an Adjacency list is

1. With Adjacency List and Priority queue:

   `O((v+e) log v)`. If the graph is dense, then `e` will be `v^2`. (Fo example, a complete graph has `(n(n/1)/2) = O(v^2)` edges, so `e >> v`.)

For denser graphs, we can use a Fibonacci Heap instead of a priority queue.

2. With Adjacency List and Fibonacci Heap:

   TC will be `O( e + v log v)`
   since in denser graph `e ~ v^2`
   TC will be `O(v^2 + v log v) ~ O(v^2)`